# How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Gradle for a Selenium TestNG project?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, testng

I want to build my Selenium WebDriver TestNG project in a single executable JAR with all dependencies.

How can I make a Gradle project package all dependency JARs into my output JAR?

Answer (score 0):

```
You neeed to write testrunner clas and by running that you will get jar files of selenium project

    package TestNGRunner_ExecutableFile;

import ExtentReports.ExtentReporterNG;
import WorldAirfaresTests.Footerlinks;
import WorldAirfaresTests.HeaderLinks;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestRunner {


    static TestNG testNg;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExtentReporterNG rep=new ExtentReporterNG();

        testNg=new TestNG();

        testNg.setTestClasses(new Class[]++++++.class, ++++++.class});
        testNg.addListener(rep);
        testNg.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: ++++++.class means the class name of your project you can add all class files which are under your automation project, then you will get a created a folder in your project  its called META-INF

Comment: ExtentReporterNG is a listener which will create HTML test reports. Does this create JAR files as well?

Comment: Yeah, our xml file listen extent report and at same time generate jar executable file